# Twig inclusion get error from vars?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, yaml

I am new to `symfony` and I am trying to make some tests.

My first test is to make a page including header and footer.
I have created controllers files in bundle:

- DefaultController.php
- FooterController.php
- SecurityController.php

for the `login` tests.

I have also created three `twig files` in

### "Resources/views/Default"

> - footer.html.twig
> - head.html.twig
> - index.html.twig

Now for first, I have tried to include in `index.html.twig` the file `footer.html.twig`, with the code:

```
{% extends 'AcmeSecurityBundle:Default:footer.html.twig' %}
```

Now, if there is only text or tags, all works better. But if i declare in the footer controller some vars and put this code in the twig file:

```
{{ year }}
{{ lastyear }}
{{ copyright }}
```

Symfony gets me the `500 Internal Error`, with

> "Variable "year" does not exist in AcmeSecurityBundle:Default:footer.html.twig at line 7" message.

How can Ipass `FooterController.php` `variables` in a `twig inclusion`?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but you have several misunderstandings.    Having index extend footer (instead of including it) makes no sense.  Best to take the time and read through the templating chapter to understand the basics.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: I'm still reading, i need to take practice whit this framework.
Now i've understand and resolved.

i've used this code  

 {% block footer %}  
 {{ render(controller('AcmeSecurityBundle:Footer:Footer')) }}  
 {% endblock %}  
  
Now i'm very happy ^_^